# calling with both single and double index

Tags: matlab

i have the following:

v=[1 2 ; 3 4]

```
 v =   
         1     2

         3     4
```

as a 4 by 4 matrix  is beeing read in thefollowing manner

```
                        2     4           (1,2)     (2,2)

                        1     3           (1,1)     (2,1)
```

So

```
1 is (1,1)
2 is (1,2)
3 is (2,1)
4 is (2,2)
```

Now if I want to call it as single index I am having a problem since:

v(1) is 1
but v(2) is 3 it is reading as:

```
              3     4
              1     2
```

if i call it as 2 index i will have several loops which wont be easy, but if i use single index the referencing is switched i am getting wrong answers.
how to solve this?

thanks hope i am clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can simply transpose your matrix and use a single index. For more complicated indexing issues you may find `shiftdim` to be useful.

Comment: thanks transpose worked for now. Hope it won't make problems later